# how to auto redirect a page based on given time? should i use javascript ? how?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

let's say i have this code

```
$itemtoDisplayTime = $model->getItemTime()  // e.g 03:00pm
$currentTime = date('H:i'); //this is the system clock/time
```

is it appropriate to use javascript to automate the process of redirection without having to refresh the page ?
if so, how ?

let's say the $itemDisplayTime is now equal to $currentTime , how to use these variables in javascript or jquery if possible

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First calculate after how many seconds it should redirect. Then use the seconds in the following methods.

For your case strtotime might work.

```
$seconds = strtotime($itemtoDisplayTime) - time();
```

There are several ways to redirect,

1. Send a `Refresh` header from PHP.

   ```
   header("Refresh: $seconds; url=$url");
   ```
2. Using Javascript

   ```
   window.setTimeout(function(){
       location.href="desired url";
   }, seconds*1000);
   ```

Comment: with that option 2, what's the use of the milliseconds ?, because my objective is like this in PHP, `if($itemtoDisplayTime === $currentTime) {  redirect the page automatically }`

Comment: if you want to execute such `if` statement you need to run this query every minutes. I wouldn't do it.  Its better to start a timer that redirects after some time. You calculate the duration first then start the timer. See the update.

Comment: option 1, won't redirect automatically right? , let's say the user is staring at the page and waiting for the item to get displayed

Comment: @sasori it'll redirect **automatically** after certain time.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want to use javascript, when you can use php to do this, Try this way

```
if($itemDisplayTime==$currentTime)
header( "refresh:0;url=yourpage.php" );
```

Comment: @SergiuDumitriu i guess he will have check current time using ajax, and when they both are equal redirect to given page.

Comment: this answer will not redirect the page automatically , correct ?, because it's pure php, i think javascript can do automated redirection...but how to do that using the php condition in your example without having to refresh nor execute the same page

Comment: @sasori yup you will have to execute script to get current time continuously although i would prefer shiplu.mokadd.im answer

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what your goal is I would say there are two possible solutions.

If you want to refresh a page to do database tasks I would suggest cron-jobs if your host supports it. Because then you can have your computer shut off and the tasks run server-side all by themselves one example of that would be: (The time is chosen on your hosts website)

```
php -q /home/path_to_file/your_link.php >/dev/null 2>&1
```

If this is for some other purpose and you would have to use ajax; because if you use getItemTime I think it would just get it once when the page first loads, you would need to keep making calls every few minutes to re-execute the java-function and re-check the time but that would get into a lot more complicated of a solution. If you would like to try this way please explain more thoroughly what the task in mind you are trying to do so I can make specific code.